# mongodb find from array and then from object id by refrence

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I want to seach order list with product division id. means i can provide division id and get order list of that perticular division.

I'm trying this query, but it return 0 elements

```
db.getCollection('orders').find({$or:
[{'orderlist':{"$elemMatch":{'product_id.division_id':ObjectId("5f5b1511a859865ac9b0efe5")}}}]
})
```

My Order Schema

```
const orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    orderlist: [{
        product_id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product', required: [true, "Product Id is Required"] },
        quantity: { type: Number, required: [true, "Product Quantity is Required"] },
        packing_type: { type: String, default: null }
    }]
});
```

My Product Schema

````
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    division_id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Division', required: [true, "Product Division Id is Required"] },
    name: { type: String, required: [true, "Product Name is Required"] },
    price: { type: Number, required: [true, "Product Price is Required"] },
    description: { type: String, required: [true, "Product Description is Required"] },
    technical_detail: { type: String, default: null },
    packing: { type: String, default: null },
    packing_type: { type: String, default: null }
});```
````

Answer (score 0):

To filter query calls with a ref schema first of all you need to lookup it from the server. In your case, it is a mongoose object id not an object of elements.
To merge schemas I recommend using aggregation.[$lookup(aggregation)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

```
db.getCollection('orders').aggregate([
{
  $lookup: {
    from: 'product',
    localField: 'orderlist.product_id',
    foreignField: '_id',
    as: 'products',
  },
},
])
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but i want to fetch order list by division_id, and division_id is in product model.
means roughly i can say it is: 

orderlist is array in which product id exists and I have to find by product_id.division_id;